# A problem on Jets in algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $k$ be a perfect field, let $n$ and $m$ be two positive integers.

Consider $X=\mathbb P_k^n\times \mathbb P_k^m$. Let $x_0=(1,0,\cdots,0;1,0,\cdots,0)\in X$ be fixed.

For any pair of integers $(d_1,d_2)$, let $\mathcal O(d_1,d_2)=pr_1^\ast \mathcal O(d_1)\otimes pr_2^\ast \mathcal O(d_2)$.

Let $A$ be a affine space(vector space) over $k$ which contains all sections of $\mathcal O(d_1,d_2)$.

For any $x\in X$ and any integer $r\geq 0$, let $B(x,r)$ be the affine space whose points are $r$-jets of sections of $\mathcal O(d_1,d_2)$.

For any $x\neq x_0$ and any two positive numbers $N$ and $M$, if $d_1$ and $d_2$ are large enough, 
I believe that the canonical restriction map is surjective
$A\longrightarrow B(x_0,N)\times B(x,M)$.

But I don't know how to show it. Any comment is very welcome!

Comment: What is this $Spec$? $\ \Gamma(X,\mathcal {O}(d_1,d_2))$ is not a ring.

Comment: Thank you~ A is a affine space over k, not the spectral...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak{m}$ (resp. $\mathfrak{m}_0$) be the maximal ideal sheaf at $x$ (resp. $x_0$). Put $L:=\mathcal{O}(d_1,d_2)$.

If I understand correctly, you are asking whether the restriction map 
$$H^0(X,L)\rightarrow (L/\mathfrak{m}^rL)\times (L/\mathfrak{m}_0^rL)$$ (or maybe $\mathfrak{m}^{r+1}$, this depends on your conventions) is surjective. Because of the exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow \mathfrak{m}^r\mathfrak{m}_0^rL \rightarrow L \rightarrow (L/\mathfrak{m}^rL)\times (L/\mathfrak{m_0}^rL)\rightarrow 0\ ,$$
this is equivalent to the vanishing of $H^1(X, \mathfrak{m}^r\mathfrak{m}_0^rL)$; this vanishing is guaranteed by Serre's theorem for $L$ ample enough, that is, $d_1,d_2\gg 0$.

Comment: the four $r$ in the exact sequence should be replaced by N and M, but the proof is still work.  Thank you very much!